# Resolving @salesforce modules on Heroku

Tags: heroku, salesforce

My company has an app on Salesforce Platform that we are planning to expand. I'm researching the pros and cons of hosting the expanded features on Heroku, instead of more on Salesforce. One of the biggest drawback I see currently is not being to access @salesforce modules, but I cannot find documentation for that. Would you know if @salesforce modules can be imported?

ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_salesforce_modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some, but not all, base Lightning Web Components can be used in [open source LWC-based applications](https://lwc.dev/) built on the Heroku platform or elsewhere. Learn more about LWC OSS at [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-apps-lightning-web-components-open-source).

However, other parts of the Lightning Web Component ecosystem are specific to the Salesforce platform. For example, in LWC OSS, you cannot import from within `@salesforce/apex`. You also won't be able to import from modules like `@salesforce/schema`, which provides schema details of your org, when you're not deploying code and metadata *in* your org.

What you'll be able to use is the portions of LWC that are built on standard JavaScript, but not the interaction with your Salesforce org. If you need to interact with the org, you'd have to establish your own API connection and make all of the calls yourself.